# How can I implement Push method in a C# desktop application?

Tags: c#

I have my software(.NET)  running on clients. I need to push the updates to the clients whenever available.

I thought to implement a web service which is running on the main server which broadcasts the update notifications to the client. For dat, CLient has to register their identity over the web to the server.

Server will send the notification on availability of the update. Client has to download the update from the server.

Will WCF would be the good option? .. Is that possible to implement? .. I know there are so many constraints in the networked environment.  Suggestions are welcome...

Comment: Voting to close because the scope of this question is vast. There are many things to consider, including manoeuvring around UAC, server choices etc etc. Narrow down your question scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table for application details including version and in application loading check the version of the application against last version number in database via a webservice if the versions are different fire error method to notify the client there is a new version of his application

but that I think valid from the start but you says the application is already running so I think you have to add this feature to the application and reinstall it on client machine.

check the following posts it may help you to find what you looking for

http://www.installsite.org/cgi-bin/frames.cgi?url=http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_patch.htm

[Is there a standard way for .NET Winforms apps to auto-upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743650/is-there-a-standard-way-for-net-winforms-apps-to-auto-upgrade)

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/10045/1763

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/DDayUpdate_Part1.aspx

Comment: Wat about pushing update from server to the client rather than client initiated???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "long polling" is a solution. Consider this scenario: Your clients connect to a server using a timeout of lets say 60 minutes. If your server has an update it sends the data and closes the connection causing your client to reconnect and wait for the next update.

[Wikipedia: Comet (Programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Since you provided details regarding infrastructure and communications I'll go with long polling again. Here is an example (first hit for "WCF long polling" on Google):

[Simple Long Polling in WCF - Server](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/banderton/2010/07/30/simple-long-polling-wcf-server)

Comment: Long polling is a "hack" to allow push to browser clients via HTTP. It is completely unnecessary for a desktop client that has full access to the network stack.

Comment: I'm with you on the hack argument. But we don't know much about the system design. Maybe the source is a web server. I'm guessing here, so more information would be quite useful, Rajesh.

Answer (score -1):

Write a windows service which runs on the clients and periodically checks the update server for new version of your software.